# styling additional <hr> tag?

Tags: css, styling

I am looking to style an additional `<hr>` tag for my side-bar on my website.

How might I be able to do this if I already have an hr defined?

```
hr { border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 22px 0 21px; height: 0; }
```

Could I add a style?

```
hr.side { border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 22px 0 21px; height: 0; }
```

so html would be

`<hr class="side">` ?

Comment: Yes, but class instead of style

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use

```
hr.side { border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 22px 0 21px; height: 0; }
```

then

```
<hr class="side">
```

in css the `.` refers to a class , and  `#` to id

EDIT:

if you really really wanted to do inline styling with `style=""` then it would look like this

```
<hr style="border: solid #ddd; border-width: 1px 0 0; clear: both; margin: 22px 0 21px; height: 0;">
```

This last method is not really the recommended way, but works great if you want to override all css style sheets, and also override any `<style> </style>`  tags that are embedded in HTML page